# Why max and min in Guava for empty arrays throw IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, guava

I'm reading the code of Guava's `Ints.max(int... array)` (and similarly, `Ints.min`, `Longs.min`, etc.) They throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `array.length == 0` (This is Guava 15.0).

I wonder why they do not return the "identity element" in this case, instead of throwing an exception. By "identity element" I mean the element behaving like 1 for product, or 0 for sum.
That is, I would expect `Ints.min()` to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `Ints.max()` to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and so on.

The rationale behind this is that if you split an array in two, the min of the whole array must be the min between the mins of both sub arrays. Or, for the mathematically inclined, the sum over an empty set of real numbers is 0, the product is 1, the union of an empty collection of sets is the empty set, and so on.

Since Guava libraries tend to be carefully produced, I guess there must be an explanation for throwing an exception here. So the question is: why?

**Edit:** I understand that most people expect max and min of an array to be an element of the array, but this is because max/min of two elements is always one of them. On the other hand, if one regards max/min just as (commutative) binary operations, returning the identity element makes more sense. To me.

Comment: You probably need to ask the guava devs. Min/max of nothing is  undefined (IMHO) so guava behavior seems normal

Comment: And how, exactly, do you want to return the min element from an `int[]` if it is empty? ANY `int` value can finds its place in an `int[]`, including the extremes `Integer.{MIN,MAX}_VALUE`. Personally, I find this behaviour to be logical.

Comment: As discovered in bet below, also note Haskell doesn't do it this way, and that's a really math-inspired language.

Answer (score 8):

Because, IMHO, in 99.99% of the cases, when you ask the minimum element of an array, you want to get an element of this array, and not some arbitrary large value. And thus, most of the time, an empty array is a special condition, that needs a specific treatment. And not handling this special condition is thus a bug, signalled by an exception.

Comment: "And thus, most of the time, an empty array is a special condition" this is a matter of religion. Any mathematician will prefer a proof or program that uniformly treats the empty set, and without checking I would bet money that an implementation of max or min in a language like Haskell will be per the OP's design.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ouch. Pretty pertinent to the OP's question, if *even* them mathy language doesn't do it the mathy elegant way then there's probably actually a pretty good reason not to do it that way.

Comment: I tried Haskell also before reading your bet ;-) As stated, they also throw an exception. But functions or/and :: [Bool] -> Bool, which are very similar to max/min from a math viewpoint, do return False and True respectively for empty lists.

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself -

> The rationale behind this is that if you split an array in two, the min of the whole array must be the min between the mins of both sub arrays. Or, for the mathematically inclined, the sum over an empty set of real numbers is 0, the product is 1, the union of an empty collection of sets is the empty set, and so on.

So [-1] = [-1] union [] but max([-1]) != max([-1] union []). I agree that for product or sum it makes more sense to return the respective identity, but not max/min.

I also prefer the property that max/min(S) be an element of S. Not some element having no relevance with respect to less than and greater than.

In particular if I'm working in a domain with a lot of negative numbers - say temperatures in Northern Canada - a day where my sample of temperatures is empty because the thermometer broke - it should not randomly show up as a relatively very warm day.

Comment: What I mean is max([-1]) == max(max([-1]), max([])). This would be true if max([]) was Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: @matiasg I see, yes, those are identities. Guava's seems like a reasonable and even good design decision to me, but I don't see any theoretical reason not to prefer yours.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum/maximum of array values must come from that array.  If the array is empty, there there is no value to take.  Returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` OR `Integer.MIN_VALUE` here would be wrong, because those values aren't in the array.  Nothing is in the array.  Mathematically, the answer is the empty set, but that isn't a valid value among possible `int` values.  There is no possible `int` correct answer, so the only possible correct course of action is to throw an `Exception`.

Comment: The answer can't be the empty set, this makes no sense at all (consider `min` of a set of sets with some total order and you'll see why). I agree with everything else you wrote, especially that the answer must come from that array. That's a difference between maximum and supremum.